# Which files replaced strstrea.h and stdiostr.h?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to migrate current code from vs6.0 to vs2010.

While compiling the code I am getting errors, such as

> "Cannot open include file: 'stdiostr.h': No such file or directory"

I have two files included in the code...

1. `stdiostr.h`
2. `strstrea.h`

But these two files are not there in my Visual Studio 2010 include folder not even `stdiostr` and `strstrea` files. Whereas in Visual Studio 6.0's include folder the files are present.

So can any one tell which files I should include to make this code work with Visual Studio 2010?

Somewhere on the Internet I read `strstream` is the alternative for `strstrea`. Is is true?

Answer (score 3):

I think following links can be helpful for your question.

> You will have to remove any old iostream headers (`fstream.h`,
>   `iomanip.h`, `ios.h`, `iostream.h`, `istream.h`, `ostream.h`, `streamb.h`, and
>   `strstrea.h`) you have included in your code and add one or more of the
>   new Standard C++ iostream headers (`<fstream>`, `<iomanip>`, `<ios>`,
>   `<iosfwd>`, `<iostream>`, `<istream>`, `<ostream>`, `<sstream>`, `<streambuf>`,
>   and `<strstream>`, all without the `.h` extension)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154419

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h8eh904(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h8eh904%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Q7: Why am I getting "compiler error C2371: 'identifier' redefinition; different basic types"?
>
> A7:In versions of Visual C++ that are earlier than Visual C++ 2005, mixing Standard C++ headers and old iostream headers causes this error, even if they are included in different source files. The following are the different headers:
>
> Old iostream Headers
> FSTREAM.H    IOMANIP.H
> IOS.H    IOSTREAM.H
> ISTREAM.H    OSTREAM.H
> STDIOSTR.H   STREAMB.H
> STRSTREA.H

**Source**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154419

There is not a one-to-one mapping between these and the headers from the C++ Standard Library.

I recommend you remove references to these files and then insert the headers you need for the specific declarations in the Standard headers.

You may well find that some of the old types have been deprecated since the VC++ 6.0 days. http://en.cppreference.com/ is a good source of information here.